# See permissions for new files on a given directory

Tags: linux, permissions, umask

I don't understand how my Linux machine is operating on new files.

I have an Amazon Linux AMI (RHEL based distro) and when I execute `umask` I get `0002`, so I get whenever I create new stuff other users won't get `write` access.

But then I go to my home directory and I type:

```
$ mkdir myDir
$ touch myDir/myFile
$ ls -l | grep myDir
```

and I get

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 myself myself 4096 May 11 22:37 myDir
```

and for the folder:

```
$ ls -l myDir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myself myself 0 May 11 22:37 myFile
```

So apparently there's more going on there then my `umask`, since `myFile` permissions are more restrictive than just `write` protection.

Digging deeper, if I try:

```
$ sudo touch /var/run/myPidFile.pid
$ ls -l /var/run/ | grep myPidFile.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root       0 May 11 22:42 myPidFile.pid
```

So `myPidFile.pid` gets a much more restrictive default permission, under `/var/run` then `myFile` gets under my home folder.

We could blame the `root` `umask` but if I run `umask` under `root` I get `0022` which is indeed more restrictive then my user's `0002` `umask` but still doesn't explain how the execution bit permission isn't set.

**So how can I understand a folder's default permission on Linux?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The umask is most of the puzzle. Root has a different umask. This is pretty typical.

The part of the puzzle that you're missing is that the umask is a *mask*. When an application creates a file, it specifies some permissions; the umask is a filter for these permissions that removes some permission bits. The file only has permission bits that the application included. For example, an application that intends to create a non-executable file (such as `touch`) passes the permission bits 666 (in octal); with the umask 002 this results in permissions 664, i.e. rw-rw-r--: the umask removed the write-other bit. When creating a directory, the application (such as `mkdir`) would normally allow execution, and so specify 777 as the permissions; the umask 002 results in permissions 775 on the directory, i.e. rwxrwxr-x.

You can see what permissions the application uses by [observing the system calls it makes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace). For example:

```
$ strace -e open,mkdir touch foo
… skipping opening of dynamically linked libraries etc. …
open("foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ strace -e open,mkdir mkdir goo
… skipping opening of dynamically linked libraries etc. …
mkdir("goo", 0777)                      = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Hmm interesting... Are there any configuration files that can change the permissions `touch` or other programs give by default?

Comment: @mFeinstein Not with `touch` or `mkdir`, and not with most programs. The umask is the configuration for file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A directory needs execute permissions on it to change into it or get a listing, so when a directory is made it automagically gets the +x bits set.

Files however only need the execute bit(s) set if they are a compiled binary (c/c++/etc) or an interpret-able script (sh/bash/php/perl/etc), as well as not making things executable by default for security reasons.

Comment: And is this default behavior configured somewhere? Like in a configuration file where I can change it? And how do you explain the different permissions for new files on 2 different folders? Following your logic they both should be configured the same way